# How to make the ChildWindow Fullscreen?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a ChildWindow , in which I have a Video Playing in Expression MediaPlayer.

When I press the FullScreen Button then the whole Application switch to FullScreen Mode, but I want only the Child Window to be Full Screen.

Answer (score 0):

A child window can't be made fullscreen. Its a security restriction.

Answer (score -1):

To do this make you form property : MDIChile = true

so you can see your full screen window into you parent window.

got it.